# An Irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

I want to prove that $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. I noticed that this polynomial can be rewritten as $x(x+1)(x^2+1)+1$. As seen, it has no proper divisor because of the constant term $1$. However, I need a rigorous proof. Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is the cyclotomic polynomial for $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)$.

Let me prove a more general case:

Proposition: If $p$ is a prime number, then the polynomial $f(x) = x^{p - 1} + x^{p - 2} + \cdots + x + 1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Proof: It suffices to show that $g(x) = f(x + 1)$ is irreducible.

Since $f(x) = \frac{x^p - 1}{x - 1}$, we have $$g(x) = \frac{(x + 1)^p - 1}{x} = x^{p- 1} + \binom{p}{p - 1}x^{p-2} + \cdots + \binom{p}{2}x + \binom{p}{1}.$$ Notice that

- all the coefficients of $g$ are divisible by $p$, except the leading coefficient $1$;
- the constant term is $p$, which is not divisible by $p^2$.

It then follows from [Eisenstein's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) that $g$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Nice answer, but I do believe this is a dup

Comment: Why this statement is true: "It suffices to show that g(x)=f(x+1) is irreducible" ?

Comment: @DonThousand Ah... all right ^_^

Comment: @HusseinEid Check the duplicate answer please!

Comment: @DonThousand Reading through the duplicate answer, I think it might worth leaving the answer here, since the accepted answer there uses much deeper mathematics, while this proof of mine is more elementary and accessible to e.g. students of lower levels.

Comment: @HusseinEid Because if $f(x) = a(x)b(x)$ is reducible then it follows that $g(x) = f(x + 1) = a(x + 1)b(x + 1)$ is also reducible.